# Shortcut extension hidden and target is off-site

Tags: shortcuts

I recently bought a printer that I connected to using Wi-Fi Direct.  I was confused in researching the security aspects, so I installed NetSpot on an administrator account to see if I can get some insight into what is going on.  I am new to both Wi-Fi Direct and NetSpot.

My non-administrator account didn't seem to have access to the installed NetSpot.  If I clicked Start, typed NetSpot, and click on what comes up, I am prompted to install.  I would rather run the app that was installed as administrator.

I followed the administrator account's Start menu shortcut for NetSpot, and tracked it down to "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Etwok Inc".  It displays as NetSpot, even though the folder view is to not hide extensions.  Cygwin shows it as NetSpot.appref-ms. Vim shows the content to be

```
https://www.netspotapp.com/download/Win/NetSpot.application#NetSpot.application, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a95f26ea3edf7f40, processorArchitecture=msil
```

I am puzzled by a number of things about this shortcut.

**Why is the extension hidden, despite the folder's view settings?**

Since the shortcut resides in a user-specific folder and it points offsite, **does that mean it's downloading the executable for each user that runs NetSpot?  Is this done every time that NetSpot is invoked?**

Comment: Catch me if I am wrong.. but "NetSpot.appref-ms" is not a shortcut, nor are the contents you show from that text document.  I unfortunately can't tell you what is going on with it so some help I am..

Comment: I assumed it was a shortcut based on the tiny arrow on the corner of the icon. Some webpages still call it a shortcut, but not to an onsite executable. I found background [here](https://fileinfo.com/extension/appref-ms), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10766334/how-to-find-the-target-exe-file-of-appref-ms), and [here](https://www.lifewire.com/application-file-2619655). So it seems like it downloads an executable on each invocation. If it's a user's first time, maybe it recognizes the absence of context files and prompts for installation. Not sure why the extension is hidden, though.

Comment: IN MY FACE!  I AM WRONG.. some sort of new fangled thingy.. perhaps Universal Windows junk.. will figure out shortly.

Comment: Mine is sitting in "C:\Users\<ME>\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\R72YQ6ER.KTC\2TJ4N36T.BM7\nets..tion_a95f26ea3edf7f40_0002.000d_2445f5fbd6a75f28\NetSpot.exe".  This is ***ClickOnce*** garbage that until today, I thought that NOBODY used.  Here is a whole page [talking about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10766334/how-to-find-the-target-exe-file-of-appref-ms)

Comment: At first, I was aghast.  But considering what runs just from visiting a typical webpage, I started to doubt that such a reaction was warranted. P.S. Not at the computer where it was installed, but will look for the `*.exe` using the path that you found. How did you locate the `*.exe`?

Comment: I used the system internals process explorer.  And from what I read about the API, the webpage part is to check for updates.. hrrrmmm.. who knows?

Comment: OK, thanks.  I don't think I'll go that extra step.  I don't think NetSpot will dispel my ignorance about the security issues with Wi-Fi Direct anyway.